# iCloud: Remove files from a device without deleting them in the cloud

Tags: macos, iphone, icloud

I've got iCloud for a few months. Have to say that I've already started to appreciate it. But there's one thing which isn't clear too me.

I've loaded a lot of education videos which where orginally stored upon my Mac into iCloud.
Now I download such a single video to my iPhone for watching it during my daily commutes. It's clear to me that the limited storage upon the iPhone will be full soon if I continuee that way.

**Is there a way to give the files back to the cloud without deleting them (in iCloud)?**

If I just delete them on the iPhone they would be deleted in the iCloud too? I currently guess so ...

What I want is basically to say: 'Remove it from the iPhone BUT keep it in iCloud!'

Comment: How did you download the video to the phone (in which app)?

Comment: By "clicking" these "cloud arrow-down" in the user-interface of the iCloud app. Please see "iCloud Download icon" / "Available for download" : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203564

Comment: @mizech you can use optimise storage in iPhone.

Comment: Why not disabling iCloud on your iPhone?